# jquery ui effect with meteor onRendered callback not working

Tags: jquery-ui, meteor

I want to add a jquery ui effect to a div element when the template is rendered , so I tried using the onRendered callback :

```
Template.home.onRendered(function(){

 this.$('.hidden').show('fold',1000).removeClass('hidden');

  });
```

the removeClass bit work , but the effect is not working , is there any solution to this problem ?

Comment: Why are you defering this event? Also, drop `this.` at start as it is not needed

Comment: when I'm not using `Meteor.defer` , the div element remains hidden when the template is rendered

Comment: @Sindis , you're right , `Meteor.defer` is not needed , but the jquery ui effect is not working

Comment: Do you mean `$('.hidden')`? It seems to be a class.

Comment: yes it's `$('.hidden') ` , I mistyped `$('.hidden') ` as `$('hidden') `

Comment: what do you want to see happening and what do you see? If I read this code right it should first show the element with a fold animation, and only then you are removing the hidden class, which, I assume, means that the element will only really be shown then. If that's the case then I wouldn't expect to see any effect/animation. Don't you want to remove the hidden class first?

Comment: I want to see a fold animation on the div element, the problem is that the element is rendered without any effect , I tried `fadeIn` , same problem ... if I remove the hidden class first, I think any effect won't take place because the element must be hidden first then we show it , I will try it

Comment: it worked finally ! , I created a new template which contains just the div element , thank you for your insightful remarks.